# accessing attr attribute from image array using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
            $(document).ready($(function () {
                var images = $("img.landscape");
                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    if (images[i].attr("src") == "") {
                        images.hide();
                    }
                }
            }));
        </script>
```

here is my jquery function. I am rendering pictures and text from a database using a repeater. some images will be empty thought and these need to be made invisible. images[i].attr("src") this piece of code seems not to be working cause it will not access the attr method. I am a novice at jquery and would appreciate any help given. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready($(function () {
  $("img.landscape").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('src') == ''){
      $(this).hide();
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help your solution worked after i added an extra bracket to the last set of closing brackets. thank you very much, was very appreciated

Answer (score -1):

After you check for an empty source, you need to hide the individual image.

Replace:

```
images.hide();
```

With:

```
images[i].hide();
```